# Enable Cookies to continue

Tags: magento-1.8, cookie

I have just installed Magento 1.8, when I login it shows me this message:

> Please enable cookies in your web browser to continue.

I have enabled cookies. I am using Chrome. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 4):

You are seeing the `enable-cookies` CMS page, which is shown if the event `controller_action_nocookies` is triggered. This happens in `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action` if:

1. The configuration *Web > Browser Capabilities Detection > Redirect to CMS-page if Cookies are Disabled* is set to *Yes*, **AND**
2. No cookie has been sent back by the browser yet (i.e. `$_COOKIE` is empty) **AND**
3. The current controller action is in the `$_cookieCheckActions` property of the controller and there is no `nocookie=1` parameter.

Logging in and creating an account are controller actions, that require a cookie check, as you can see in `Mage_Customer_AccountController`:

```
/**
 * Action list where need check enabled cookie
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $_cookieCheckActions = array('loginPost', 'createpost');
```

You could disable the cookie check configuration (see (1)), but this won't solve the problem because without a session cookie you won't be able to log in anyway.

The problem lies in Magentos cookie management configuration. Please check it at **Web > Session Cookie Management**. It should look similar to this:

[image: config screenshot]

- "Cookie Lifetime": a sufficiently big value in seconds
- "Cookie Path": the path to your Magento installation relative to the document root (usually `/`)
- "Cookie Domain": the domain of your Magento installation, including www subdomain if used.
- "Use HTTP Only" can be set to "Yes" as long as you don't need to access cookies with JavaScript. I usually set it to "No" to be able to run Selenium tests.
- "Cookie Restriction Mode" should be "No", except if you are legally required to have your users allow cookies with a button click (like in France)